# Dreamweaver minified code problems

Tags: html, css, ftp, dreamweaver, minify

I am using Dreamweaver as my editor and started FTP my code to the server but it minifieds my custom HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I looked to see if it is my preferences and can't find anything that would cause that.

I also used a third party FTP tool filezilla to FTP my code but its still minified.

I also hand coded a simple CSS and uploaded it with FileZilla and it still minified it.

I also used several other host to load the pages and it sill minified my code.

Anyone has had this problem before?

This is the website I am trying to FTP http://alvertogardea.com/condo/

Comment: Dreamweaver doesn't have a minify option; this must be done by something else. Are you using WordPress or a similar framework?

Comment: No I am not using wordpress but I also tried using  Sublime Text 2 with a template I downloaded and when I made changes and save then FTP with filezilla it was became minified so it must be something in my setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try these in Dreamweaver

1. Open the file in question
2. Highlight the content (code view)
3. Click on Format source code on the left pan (Tilted bucket icon)

Following the above steps will restore the code format to your default format.

Comment: This sort of did some changes but it is still being minified. I think its some setting in my part because I used Sublime Text 2 and it still minifies it when I FTP the code. Thanks